# Exporting all shader node with object to import into another scene

Tags: export

I have a loverly loaf of bread, textures, shaded the lot but it's to be part of a much bigger scene. When I export it as any of the files types on offer in the drop down, 3ds. .abc etc., the shader nodes don't come with it and I'm left looking at something like a plastic lump. Do I have to redo all the shading/textures/normal maps etc., in the scene to which I have imported the object or is there a way to bring everything across? Also tried the append function and had no joy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From blender it is possible to link to an asset that is in another blend file. No need export/import for this. Check in the file menu under link/append.

Be aware that there is a difference between linking and appending. With linking you cannot change the linked data locally (as it will still be loaded from the original blend-file). The benefit of linking is that you can change the object/material in the original file and it will be automatic updated in all scenes where it is linked to.

Before linking works with an object. also be sure this object is in a group. And you link the group in stead of the object. Otherwise you won't be able to move the object.

By using append you will be able to change the data as a copy will be stored in the blend file you are working on. (more similar to Copy paste).

Comment: Ok this worked but then how do I find the nodes in node editor please?

Comment: I updated the reply that you need to make it a group in order to work correctly. I also added the difference between linking and appending

Answer (score 4):

You should not use the import/export tools when copying stuff from one scene to another. Use the *Append* tool in your big scene (File->Append) and choose the bread .blend file. Then navigate to the "Objects" folder in the .blend file and select all objects belonging to your loaf of bread. This will import it with all materials applied.
[image]
The alternative is to first open the bread .blend, select the bread and press `Ctrl + C` and then paste it into an other file opened with `Ctrl + v`

Comment: ok maybe i'm being dumb but when i click on the bread.blend file I can see no 'object file' even if I click on it or 2x click on it. In fact if I do click on it then go to the top right and hit append from library it takes me to main interface with a message....bread.blend not a library

Answer (score 0):

There's a few different ways to achieve it. If you plan to complete the entire project from the same local machine, you can always create a linked library. However, this can be problematic if you are sharing workflow with others, or need to import into other apps. The most fail safe way to achieve this is to bake & export all of your UV texture maps and assign them to the object. Just make sure you select "automatically pack resources" from the edit tab prior to saving.